# Precaution needed while using variable.length in javascript for array and object?

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript `length` property (`variable.length`) to find the length of an array or object.

Is there any special check required before using the length property for an array or object.

Different types of errors are found while using the `length` property in my previous experience. So I need to know the correct way to use the `length` property and possible errors while using `length` property.

Comment: In JS, some objects have length (eg. Arrays), but some haven't (eg. plain objects). What kind of object do you want to measure with it?

Comment: I am using array or object created through the html selection like $('.variations').find('.fields'); so this will return an object.

Comment: Yes, but a special object (jQuery object), which will always have length. Use it without precautions!

Answer (score 0):

You need check if the array is different to `undefined` or `null`, after that, you can get the `length` property. Also you can use Array.isArray() to check if is `array` the variable

[isArray reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/isArray)

Comment: Plain objects doesn't have length, bit they're still objects. And.... strings do have length as well...

Comment: Then you can first determine that variable is Array or not by using Array.isArray function of javascript

Comment: the objects haven't length property, so when you use Array.isArray(object) the result will be false and you will know that you can't use length property... and with the strings, You can see as array of characters

Answer (score 0):

You can access every property (also the "length") property on everything, except on `null` and `undefined`. In most cases `.length` is `undefined` then though.

Comment: so we only need to check the variable is undefined or null ? How we need to check this ?

Answer (score -1):

The `length` attribute can be found in multiple data structures.

The length in `String.prototype.length` or in `Array.length`.

For any variable, you should check whether the variable itself exists first and then check the length if you know that it will have length attribute like for arrays.

```
// This will be applicable for data structures with length attribute
if (variable && variable.length) {}

// If you don't know the data structure
if (('length' in variable) && (variable.length >= some_num)) {}
```

Comment: Many time we will get error like Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, Cannot read property 'length' of null. The above check is enough for this also ??

Comment: Yes. This `'length' in variable` check would do just fine or you could use `variable.hasOwnProperty('length')`